# form resubmission in php, how to redirect to specific pages

Tags: php

I'm having i small problem with form resubmission in php, when ever the form is filled on my Site, and submitted, they are redirected back.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //process form input and validate data here 
        if ( strlen(isset($_POST['name'])) > 0 ){
            //return status to user here
            //and redirect page here.
?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
           history.go(-2);
        </script>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

This is where i'm having problem, i'm using javascript to redirect to the previous page. I need the browser to redirect to the previous page, but if it is login.php, then it should redirect to the previous page before login.php, how do i do this in php, to get the previous page and redirect the browser to the previous page, but if the previous page is login.php, then it should redirect to the one before it.

Comment: Why don't you set a `Location:` header instead?

Comment: you should look into this `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Brad, I can't use location because, i already sent some output with echo before the form submission, which is not making the header('Location') work, or is there another way to use the Location method that i'm not getting?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact solution, but to redirect people use the following:

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
```

To use the above code it must be displayed before any other information is displayed to the page.

To redirect the user to the page they came from use the following:

```
header('Location: '+$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Be careful when using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` as that url is set by the user agent and isn't always there.

If you really need to redirect to the page they were on before they were redirected to the login page you need to either store that information into a $_SESSION[] variable or make it a GET var in the url.

Example:

1. User goes to http://www.example.com/settings.php
2. User isn't logged in redirect them to `login.php?redirect=http://www.example.com/settings.php` or before redirecting set `$_SESSION['redirect'] = "http://www.example.com/settings.php";`
3. Handle Login

   - Login failed redirect them to `login.php?redirect=http://www.example.com/settings.php` or login.php (if you used SESSION variable).
   - Login successful redirect with `header('Location: '+$_GET['redirect']);` or `header('Location: '+$_SESSION['redirect']);`

[More Information on Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

[More Information on $_SERVER variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

[More Information on header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: do i necessarily have to store it in a session variable? Can't i just get it and redirect them?

Comment: @samsonade, I posted 2 options. 1 is session vars and the other is to post it as a GET var in the url. Other than that I don't know of a viable solution. Don't even think there is another solution that is entirely different.